# $_SESSION not registered

Tags: php, session, authentication, passwords

What is wrong in this codes?

Login.html:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['password'])) {
    header("location:admin.php");
    } else {

echo "<html>
<head>
<title>
FLG iRadio Station
</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/main.css' />
</head>
<body>
<center>
TO LOGIN, SUBMIT PASSWORD
<form name='login' id='login' method='POST' action=logincheck.php>
 <input type='password' NAME='password' id='password' maxlength='15' />
 <input type='submit' value='Submit Password'/>
 </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>";

    }
?>
```

logincheck.php:

```
<?php
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if($password == "flgpdrii"){
    session_register("password");
    header("location:admin.php");
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Wrong Password! <a href='login.html'>Login again</a>";
    }
?>
```

admin.php:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['password'])) {
        echo "Welcome Admin";
    } else {
        echo "Login <a href='login.html'>here</a>";
    }
    echo $_SESSION['password'];
?>
```

and logout.php:

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Delete certain session
unset($_SESSION['username']);
// Delete all session variables
session_destroy();

// Jump to login page
header('Location: login.html');
?>
```

Entering a correct password,it will redirect to admin.php with echoed "Login here".
it must be "Welcome Admin"

anyone can help?

Comment: Have you tried testing this at all? Instead of redirecting echo out various values

Comment: Why do you put a `maxlength` on a password field?!

Comment: session_register is deprecated, and one of your files misses session_start.

Comment: ... and it is the file where the password is added to the session.

Comment: what do you mean christian? thiefmaster, i dont know why i add that.. :)  .. mario and scones. i see.. i will place session_start in that file.. then checking it again if it is working.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things needs to be corrected..

1) Save Login.html as Login.php since you are using PHP code.

2) Edit Logincheck.php as below

```
<?php
     session_start();
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if($password == "flgpdrii"){
    //session_register("password");
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    header("location:admin.php");
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Wrong Password! <a href='login.html'>Login again</a>";
    }
?>
```

session_register is depreciated, better avoid it.